# Need Method to Return only matching numbers in Java

Tags: java, set, duplicates

```
/**
 * This method should compare two Sets of Integers and return a new 
 * Set of Integers that represent all of the matching numbers.
 * 
 * For example, if the lotteryNumbers are (4, 6, 23, 34, 44, 45) and
 * the userNumbers are (4, 18, 22, 24, 35, 45) then the returned Set
 * of Integers should be (4, 45)
 * 
 * @param lotteryNumbers the lottery numbers that were randomly generated.
 * @param userNumbers the user picked numbers that were picked in the console.
 * @return Set of matched numbers
 */
public Set<Integer> playLottery (Set<Integer> lotteryNumbers, Set<Integer> userNumbers)  {
    Set<Integer> listOfRandom = new HashSet<Integer>(lotteryNumbers);
    listOfRandom.equals(lotteryNumbers);
    listOfRandom.addAll(lotteryNumbers);

    Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>(userNumbers); 
    s.equals(userNumbers);
    s.addAll(userNumbers);

    Set<Integer> e = new HashSet<Integer>(); 

    for (Integer integer : userNumbers) {
        if (userNumbers.equals(lotteryNumbers));
        userNumbers.remove(lotteryNumbers);
    }
    return userNumbers;
}
```

As of now it only returns all the userNumbers. I assumed the remove() method would remove any duplicate values returned. I need this to pass my unit Test.

Answer (score 2):

`retainAll()` is what you're looking for.

```
Set<Integer> lotteryNumbers = new TreeSet<Integer>();
// ... Populate it with 4, 6, 23, 34, 44, 45 
Set<Integer> userNumbers = new TreeSet<Integer>();
// ... Populate it with 4, 18, 22, 24, 35, 45
userNumbers.retainAll(lotteryNumbers);
// userNumbers is now just (4, 45)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully, Java provides a method for this exactly called `retainAll()`. To avoid destroying either of the original sets, do something like:

```
Set<String> intersection = new HashSet<String>(lotteryNumbers);
intersection.retainAll(userNumbers);
return intersection;
```

Comment: Thanks I beat I brain on this for hours.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Apache Commons - Collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections//javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html) for operations similar to these. Specifically, you can use CollectionUtils.intersection()

```
CollectionUtils.intersection(Arrays.asList(4,6,23,34,44,45),Arrays.asList(4,18,22,24,35,45)) // returns collection with 4,45
```

The generics version is at http://sourceforge.net/projects/collections/